# Dynamic dialog boxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with `Winforms` and I have a question about making these more dynamic. For instance I can create a `winform` that has a group of text boxes that displays data however how would I make this dynamic? In terms of the number of text boxes the user can see depends on what data is found?

I know I can do something along the lines of the below:

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
```

In my scenario I have an application that reads through a bunch of documents and if a `$` is found then a prompt appears asking the user to input a proper value, however, if the document has a lot of values that need updating then this is a lot of dialog boxes. So a good way to resolve this is to have the dialog box appear at the end (after the file has been read) with all the values that need updating and the user can update all these at once.

The problem that I see is that the number of values that need to be displayed can  be anything from 1 on wards, which means the loop would need to account for this.

My current code is as below;

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
{
    current++;
    fileProcessBar.Value = current / count * 60 + 40;

    string[] alllines = File.ReadAllLines(fi.FullName);

    for (int i = 0; i < alllines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (alllines[i].Contains("$"))
        {
            // prompt
            int dollarIndex = alllines[i].IndexOf("--");
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"(--.{1,100})");
            var chars = regex.Match(alllines[i]).ToString();

            string PromptText = chars.Replace("-", "");

            string promptValue = CreateInput.ShowDialog(PromptText, fi.FullName);

            if (promptValue.Equals(""))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                alllines[i] = alllines[i].Replace("$", promptValue);
                File.WriteAllLines(fi.FullName, alllines.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
```

prompt method:

```
public static string ShowDialog(string text, string caption)
{
    Form prompt = new Form()
    {
        Width = 600,
        Height = 150,
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog,
        Text = caption,
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    };
    Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 15, Width = 500, Text = text };
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 52, Width = 500 };
    Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Add", Left = 450, Width = 100, Top = 72, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };
    confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
    prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);
    prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
    prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
    prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;
    prompt.MaximizeBox = false;


    return prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ? textBox.Text : "";  
}
```

My question is how can a `winform` be more dynamic as in terms of size and what is displayed? how can I create a new form without specifying size and position? but still not being a jumbled mess?

Comment: So what is your question? It is not clear how we can help.

Comment: @RobAnthony, I have edited my question I hope this helps. Sorry I am a little new to C#

Comment: it is still not entirely clear to me. So imagine you have 3 `$` values in your file. This should result in 3 Textboxes from Prompting? and the entire form should have 1 accept button?

Comment: Hey @MongZhu, That is correct

Comment: See [Creating a Resizable Windows Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/991eahec(v=vs.100)). Also see other [walkthroughs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zftbwa2b(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new Form with a certain size. Then add a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) to the form which has almost the same width as the form and almost the same height. Leave enough space for the button that you need:

[image]

In the panel properties set the fields `AutoSize` to true and `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink`:

[image]

Don't forget to specify the `FlowDirection`:

```
this.panel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
```

Now you need just a method which adds your prompting controls to the controls of the `FlowLayoutPanel` (which will order them in an automatic fashion) :

```
public void AddToCanvas(string text)
{
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label() {Text = text});
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new TextBox());

    Resize();

}
```

And a resize method to adjust the form to the amount of current controls inside it:

```
public void Resize()
{
    Size s = new Size();
    s.Height = this.flowLayoutPanel1.Height + this.button_Accept.Height + 
        (this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count * 10) + y_offset;
    s.Width = this.flowLayoutPanel1.Width + 10;
    this.MaximumSize = s;
    this.Size = s;
}
```

With this input:

> random text
>   $ Name
>   $ Address
>   random text
>   $ Age
>   random text
>   $ Planet
>   $ Continent
>   random text
>   $ StarSystem

I get the following Result:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Create a variable after you have read the contents of one file (before you loop through the lines):

```
DynamicPrompt dp = new DynamicPrompt("YourCaption");

for (int i = 0; i < alllines.Length; i++)
{
    if (alllines[i].Contains("$"))
    {
```

Start the loop and if you get to the important line call

```
        dp.AddToCanvas(PromptText);
```

Comment: Thanks for this I am just a little confused how I would call this in my loop.

Comment: @Tom I made an edit, have a look. you need a fresh form for every file then you can call the add method at each important line that you want to add

Comment: @Tom are you still struggling to adopt it to your problem?

Comment: I am yeah I understand what you mean but when I put this into practice I do not get the same results, I am also unsure how to record all of the values.

Comment: @Tom " I do not get the same results" what is different? I forgot to mention: Did you set in the Form the property `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink`? "how to record all of the values" that actually would be a different thread

Comment: for me the prompt does not generate this just skips through. Looking at the debug I cannot see why this is not populating :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151945/discussion-between-mong-zhu-and-tom).